# Show that stochastic integral is Gaussian by independency of increments

Tags: stochastic-processes, independence, stochastic-integrals

Let $h \in  L^2[(0,1)]$ and consider the process $(X_t)_{t \in [0,1]} = \big( \int_0^t h(s) \text{d}B_s \big)_{t \in [0,1]}$, where $B_s$ is Brownian motion.

By construction of the integral I know that $(X_t)$ has independent increments. How can I deduce from this fact that $(X_t)$ is Gaussian?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can check that each $X_t$ is Gaussian and then use the independence to deduce that $(X_t)_t$ is Gaussian (i.e. that the finite dimensional distributions are Gaussian).

Comment: @saz Ok thanks! So, since every linear combination of $X_t$'s can be written as a linear combination of increments and the sum of independent gaussian variables is gaussian the claim follows, right?

Comment: Well, yes, but you still need to show that each $X_t$ is Gaussian.

Comment: Yes, already done this. Thanks!